# How does (struct _IO_FILE *)->_IO_read_base get set?

Tags: c, file, unix, glibc, stdio

Apologies for the probably weird question title. I didn't want it to look like a dupe with a title like "How does C file I/O work at the low level?". I want it to be obvious that my question is specific.

Anyways, when a file is `fopen`'d in C, it returns a `struct _IO_FILE *`.

```
FILE *f = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
printf("Fileno: %i\n", f->_fileno); // 3
```

I've looked at `libio.h` and gdb's "tab" output, and have confirmed that the contents of a `struct _IO_FILE` are as follows:

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;
  char* _IO_read_ptr;
  char* _IO_read_end;
  char* _IO_read_base; // <-- file contents
  char* _IO_write_base;
  char* _IO_write_ptr;
  char* _IO_write_end;
  char* _IO_buf_base;
  char* _IO_buf_end;
  char *_IO_save_base;
  char *_IO_backup_base;
  char *_IO_save_end;
  struct _IO_marker *_markers;
  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;
  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset;
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];
  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
  __off64_t _offset;
  void *__pad1;
  void *__pad2;
  void *__pad3;
  void *__pad4;
  size_t __pad5;
  int _mode;
  char _unused2[...];
};
```

I've prodded at every one of them in gdb, and have noticed that `f->_IO_read_base` is `0x0` at first, but becomes a pointer to a proper string, which contains the entire contents of the file, *only* after having called `fgetc()` (or a similar function) at least once. After some gruelling and extensive searching of the glibc codebase, I seem to have tracked it down to a function called `__uflow`

So my question is, how does `_IO_read_base` get initialized? *Where* does it get the contents from? *How* does it acquire said contents? *When* does `IO_read_base` transform from a null pointer to a string? How would I go about doing this using only the struct itself and some system calls? I want to understand how this works at the low level.

```
...
(gdb) print fp->_IO_read_base 
$3 = 0x0
(gdb) n
434    in genops.c
< a few more times ... >
_IO_getc (fp=0x602010) at getc.c:38
38    getc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print fp->_IO_read_base 
$4 = 0x7ffff7ff4000 "#include <stdio.h> ..."
(gdb)
```

You can see where it transforms. Somewhere in genops.c. Presumably `__uflow()`. But its source doesn't answer any questions:

```
int
__uflow (fp)
     _IO_FILE *fp;
{
#if defined _LIBC || defined _GLIBCPP_USE_WCHAR_T
  if (_IO_vtable_offset (fp) == 0 && _IO_fwide (fp, -1) != -1)
    return EOF;
#endif

  if (fp->_mode == 0)
    _IO_fwide (fp, -1);
  if (_IO_in_put_mode (fp))
    if (_IO_switch_to_get_mode (fp) == EOF)
      return EOF;
  if (fp->_IO_read_ptr < fp->_IO_read_end)
    return *(unsigned char *) fp->_IO_read_ptr++;
  if (_IO_in_backup (fp))
    {
      _IO_switch_to_main_get_area (fp);
      if (fp->_IO_read_ptr < fp->_IO_read_end)
    return *(unsigned char *) fp->_IO_read_ptr++;
    }
  if (_IO_have_markers (fp))
    {
      if (save_for_backup (fp, fp->_IO_read_end))
    return EOF;
    }
  else if (_IO_have_backup (fp))
    _IO_free_backup_area (fp);
  return _IO_UFLOW (fp);
}
libc_hidden_def (__uflow)
```

Testing each call in gdb, every single if check fails, so I'm left to assume that it returns `_IO_UFLOW (fp);`. The funny thing is that _IO_UFLOW is a macro wrapper of `__uflow`, so...it's calling itself. And it's not recursing infinitely. Why?

And with that, I've hit a dead end, as there is *still* no explanation that I can find as to how `fp->IO_read_ptr` gets filled out. All I know is that it happens "somewhere" in `genops.c`.

Comment: Almost certainly `libc_hidden_def (__uflow)` is one of those tricky weak reference type things that allows you to override functions with identically named other functions.

Comment: @paxdiablo Y'know, sometimes I question the sanity of the GNU devs. Sure they make stellar software, but then you look at the source code and find macro spaghetti, excessive whitespace, weird indents, and all kinds of horrible, nightmarishly difficult to read code that looks like it came straight out of a code golf challenge from hell. One wonders how they haven't lost their minds maintaining it. Then again, maybe they already have...

Answer (score 1):

On platforms with hardware watchpoint support in GDB, you can answer this question trivially by setting a watchpoint on `fp->_IO_read_base`. Example:

```
(gdb) watch -l fp->_IO_read_base
Hardware watchpoint 2: -location fp->_IO_read_base
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: -location fp->_IO_read_base

Old value = 0x0
New value = 0x7ffff7ff7000 ""
__GI__IO_switch_to_get_mode (fp=fp@entry=0x602010) at genops.c:191
191 genops.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI__IO_switch_to_get_mode (fp=fp@entry=0x602010) at genops.c:191
#1  0x00007ffff7a8f670 in _IO_new_file_underflow (fp=0x602010) at fileops.c:602
#2  0x00007ffff7a841a5 in _IO_getdelim (lineptr=0x7fffffffdc88, n=0x7fffffffdc90, delimiter=10, fp=0x602010) at iogetdelim.c:77
#3  0x00000000004005b7 in main () at t.c:9
```